# population size determination

Tags: sample-size, survey, sample

I was studying statistics and came across a conducted survey; here are the elements of sample size determination.

- "We are now conducting the survey to see if beets are the best vegetable to choose as a base for our new juice. Our product manager tells us that we want to be within 4% of the correct answer, with a 95% confidence level. The town of Vancucumber is made up of 1700 people. We estimate that 40% of people think that the beet is the best vegetable. "

After reading this description, I thought the population size was 1700. However, the answer says that the population size should be at least 100000. What could be the reason for that?
There are only 1700 people in the town?

Comment: How did the solution come up with $100,000?$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a problem of population proportion. If this is the case, the problem could be solved in the following way.

The problem asks to compute the required population size, the information given is:

a) 95% confidence interval: this piece of information tell us to apply normal distribution.

b) Within 4%: this is the required error for the estimation.

c) 40%: is the proportion of people that thinks beet is the best vegetable, so this is our objective population. No matter if the town has 1,700 people or 1,000,000 people, the relevant piece of information is the proportion.

You can find the following formula in several books, one example is Montgomery Douglas C & Runger, George C, Applied Statistical and Probability for Engineers, John Wiley & Sons, Inc.

$$
n=\left( \dfrac{z_{\alpha/2}}{E}\right)^{2}p(1-p) 
$$

Use the formula to obtain the following answer

$$
n=\left( \dfrac{1.96}{0.04}\right)^{2}(0.4)(1-0.4) = 576
$$

This is far from the $100,000$ answer. So we could ask ourselves what would be the value of $E$ in order to give us some number close to the seeking answer? By trial and error, you can easily fin that

$$
n=\left( \dfrac{1.96}{0.003}\right)^{2}(0.4)(1-0.4) = 102,439
$$

You can also use Excel and create a template with formula `=NORM.INV(1-0.025,0,1)` to compute $z_{\alpha/2}$, this will help you in making what if analysis.

Hope this will be useful.